# VBA 'Object variable or With block variable not set: Error 91

Tags: excel, vba

Usually I just use other similar questions to solve my problems but I just can't sort this one myself, objects confuse me.

Basically I'm trying to create an index sheet full of hyperlinks for the user to click. However the titles will not be the sheet names. Instead each sheet will contain a couple of entries in certain cells. There are hundreds of entries so I'd rather not do this manually. Currently whilst I'm creating it, the code only references one bit of data from each sheet, but I figured it would be relatively easy to extrapolate to the rest.

```
Sub CreateLinksHospitals()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim lRow As Integer
Dim nRow As Integer
Dim Link As Object
For i = 5 To 175
lRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
nRow = lRow + 1
Worksheets(i).Activate
    If Not ActiveSheet.Range("B3") = "" Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(nRow, 1).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & sh.Name & "'" & "!A1", TextToDisplay:=sh.Name
    End If
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The error is concerning the Worksheets.Hyperlinks.Add line. Any help would be massively appreciated.

Edit:

I used something similar to create an index tab of sheet names. This worked fine. I can't find the difference as to why this one works and the one above does not.

```
Sub CreateLinksToAllSheets()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A3").Activate
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ActiveSheet.Name <> sh.Name Then
        ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
        "'" & sh.Name & "'" & "!A1", TextToDisplay:=sh.Name
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    End If
Next sh
End Sub
```

Comment: You never set `sh` to anything, yet you reference it in that line of code.

Comment: That's true! Removing it gives the error of "Object required", but adding Set sh = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells..... gives the same error 91

Comment: Something is wrong. I'm surprised you don't get a type mismatch error.  You have declared `sh` as a worksheet, yet `Set sh = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells` tries to set it to a Range object.